# Many-to-many with flask and sqlalchemy in python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to do a many-to-many relationship table with more information than just the two ids. It doesnt work. I obviously standardised my table with generic names. But the use case could be like a user table , with a post table and a likes relationship table, something like that. when i do these table, python gave me that :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Table2.rela1 - there are no foreign keys linking these tables.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify a 'primaryjoin' expression.
```

So here is my relationship table

```
class Relationship(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Table1.id')),
    table2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Table2.id')),
    value = db.Column(db.Integer), #a number
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime) #actual time of the entry
```

here is my table1

```
class Table1(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    rela1 = db.relationship('Relationship', backref = 'rel1', lazy = 'dynamic')
    rela2 = db.relationship('Table2', backref = 'rel2', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

here is my table 2

```
class Table2(db.Model):    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table1.id'))
    rela1 = db.relationship('Relationship', backref = 'rel3', lazy = 'dynamic')
```

Thanks for helping me.

If that can be solved then my second issue is creating a function to compute the total 'value' per Table2 object, regardless of the which table1 object post the value. something like a select with sum and group by table2.id , but i dont really understand how to do it with python and flask and sqlalchemy.

Thanks.

**EDIT1**

Using http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-object

i changed to

```
class Relationship(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'relationship'
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Table1.id'), primary_key = True),
    table2_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Table2.id'), primary_key = True),
    value = db.Column(db.Integer), #a number
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime) #actual time of the entry
table2obj = db.relationship("Table2", backref="table2_assocs")
```

then

```
class Table2(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'table2'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    table1_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('table1.id'))
```

and table 1 is unchanged except the addition of **tablename**

but now i get

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Relationship|relatioship could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'Relationship'
```

Comment: The code you've shown shouldn't be giving you the error you're describing.  Double check your spelling and parenthesis; make sure *every* table defines at least one `primary_key` column.  Also, tricks like `reload(myModels)` usually doesn't work with sqlalchemy.ext.declarative; restart your application.

Comment: yeah they all have a primary_key column. i tried to reload the app, but with this error, it doesnt even start.

Answer (score 0):

there are two `relationship` declarations on `Table1`, but from the code you've posted, I can see only one path to `Table2`, through `Relationship.table2_id`.

It looks like you are trying to have a many-to-many relationship with extra metadata on the intermediate relation.  This is called the [association object pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-object) in the sqlalchemy docs.  For that, everything you've got so far, except the `Table1.rela2` is good, you pretty well have it.  That "rogue" `relationship` needs to be removed.

to get the convenience of having a real relationship from `Table1` to `Table2`, you need to use an [association proxy](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects).

Comment: ok so i tried to transform my code using http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/relationships.html#association-object but now i get 

    sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|Vote|vote could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'Relationship'